How do you make an overlay div sticky relevant to a parent div that is horizontally scrollable?
Pretty much whats in the title. I am trying to make those circular buttons to be horizontal scrollable. I also would like to provide some kind of feedback to the user whether there is more to scroll to either direction, so I am trying to do it via the overlay. As of now, the overlays seem to be moving when scrolling, I would like it to stick to the sides of the circular buttons.
Here is the code I tried:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scrollable Circular Buttons</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom styles */
        .scrollable-div {
            position: relative;
            width: 50%;
            overflow-x: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 10px 0; 
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            /* Hide the scrollbar */
            scrollbar-width: none;
        }
        .scrollable-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none; /* WebKit (Safari, Chrome) */
        }
        .circular-btn {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #007bff; /* Bootstrap primary color */
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 40px;
            margin-right: 5px; /* Reduced margin */
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .scroll-overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 50px; /* Adjust as needed */
            pointer-events: none; /* Allow clicks to pass through */
        }
        .scroll-overlay-left {
            left: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);

        }
        .scroll-overlay-right {
            right: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);

        }
        .selected {
            background-color: #28a745 !important; /* Bootstrap success color */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="scrollable-div" id="scrollableDiv">
        <!-- List of circular buttons -->
        <div class="circular-btn selected">1</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">2</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">3</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">4</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">5</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">6</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">7</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">8</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">9</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">10</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">11</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">12</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">13</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">14</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">15</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">16</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">17</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">18</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">19</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">20</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">21</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">22</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">23</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">24</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">25</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">26</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">27</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">28</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">29</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">30</div>
        <!-- Scroll overlays to indicate end of content -->
        <div class="scroll-overlay scroll-overlay-left"></div>
        <div class="scroll-overlay scroll-overlay-right"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollableDiv');
            const scrollOverlayLeft = document.querySelector('.scroll-overlay-left');
            const scrollOverlayRight = document.querySelector('.scroll-overlay-right');

        // Check scroll status on initial load
            updateOverlayVisibility();

        // Update overlay visibility based on scroll position
            scrollableDiv.addEventListener('scroll', updateOverlayVisibility);

            function updateOverlayVisibility() {
                const scrollPosition = scrollableDiv.scrollLeft;
                const scrollWidth = scrollableDiv.scrollWidth;
                overlayWidth = Math.min((scrollPosition / scrollWidth) * 50 , 50);
                scrollOverlayLeft.style.width = overlayWidth + ' px';
                scrollOverlayRight.style.width = overlayWidth + ' px';
                scrollOverlayLeft.style.display = scrollPosition > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
                scrollOverlayRight.style.display = scrollPosition < scrollWidth ? 'block' : 'none';

            }

        // JavaScript for circular button selection
            const circularButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.circular-btn');

            circularButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
                btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // Remove 'selected' class from all buttons
                    circularButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
                        btn.classList.remove('selected');
                    });
                // Add 'selected' class to the clicked button
                    this.classList.add('selected');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Thanks!

You need 2 container div for this. First one which does not scroll and another which does. Your overlap will be absolute to parent one. Here is JSBIn
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scrollable Circular Buttons</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom styles */
        .scrollable-div {
            position: relative;
            width: 50%;
            overflow-x: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 10px 0; 
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            /* Hide the scrollbar */
            scrollbar-width: none;
        }
      .scrollable-div > div{
        overflow-x: auto;
      }
        .scrollable-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none; /* WebKit (Safari, Chrome) */
        }
        .circular-btn {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #007bff; /* Bootstrap primary color */
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 40px;
            margin-right: 5px; /* Reduced margin */
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .scroll-overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 50px; /* Adjust as needed */
            pointer-events: none; /* Allow clicks to pass through */
        }
        .scroll-overlay-left {
            left: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);

        }
        .scroll-overlay-right {
            right: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);

        }
        .selected {
            background-color: #28a745 !important; /* Bootstrap success color */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="scrollable-div" id="scrollableDiv">
      <div>
        <!-- List of circular buttons -->
        <div class="circular-btn selected">1</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">2</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">3</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">4</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">5</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">6</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">7</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">8</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">9</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">10</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">11</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">12</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">13</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">14</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">15</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">16</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">17</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">18</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">19</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">20</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">21</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">22</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">23</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">24</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">25</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">26</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">27</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">28</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">29</div>
        <div class="circular-btn">30</div>
        <!-- Scroll overlays to indicate end of content -->
        <div class="scroll-overlay scroll-overlay-left"></div>
        <div class="scroll-overlay scroll-overlay-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollableDiv');
            const scrollOverlayLeft = document.querySelector('.scroll-overlay-left');
            const scrollOverlayRight = document.querySelector('.scroll-overlay-right');

        // Check scroll status on initial load
            updateOverlayVisibility();

        // Update overlay visibility based on scroll position
            scrollableDiv.addEventListener('scroll', updateOverlayVisibility);

            function updateOverlayVisibility() {
                const scrollPosition = scrollableDiv.scrollLeft;
                const scrollWidth = scrollableDiv.scrollWidth;
                overlayWidth = Math.min((scrollPosition / scrollWidth) * 50 , 50);
                scrollOverlayLeft.style.width = overlayWidth + ' px';
                scrollOverlayRight.style.width = overlayWidth + ' px';
                scrollOverlayLeft.style.display = scrollPosition > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
                scrollOverlayRight.style.display = scrollPosition < scrollWidth ? 'block' : 'none';

            }

        // JavaScript for circular button selection
            const circularButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.circular-btn');

            circularButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
                btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // Remove 'selected' class from all buttons
                    circularButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
                        btn.classList.remove('selected');
                    });
                // Add 'selected' class to the clicked button
                    this.classList.add('selected');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

https://jsbin.com/nukonesidu/edit?html,output

Thank you I accepted this answer. But could you please explain how does absolute make the overlay stick here? Isnt the parent div being scrolled as well? Dont you need sticky to make it not affected by the parent div being scrolled?

Absolute positioning is done on the immediate parent which is positioned(any position except static). The new div() is not positioned so absolute position will be relative to #scrollableDiv which is positioned(position: relative)
